# Trouble creating a custom date format

Tags: excel, date

I am trying to build a custom date format that matches the format below. I've included an example of the number value (date) and how the output should look. I've tried something like: ddd mmm d, yyyy h:mm:ssAM/PM [ddd mmm d, yyyy h:mm:ssAM/PM] as a custom format, but can't seem to get it to work. Can you tell me where I am going wrong? Thank you in advance!

```
(Date time) 1546926706 = (Formatted Output) Mon Jan 7, 2019 9:51:46pm PST [Mon Jan 7, 2019 10:51:46pm]
```

Attempt at translating format into custom format Excel understands: 
`
ddd mmm d, yyyy  h:mm:ssAM/PM [ddd mmm d, yyyy h:mm:ssAM/PM]

Basically I'm trying to reverse engineer a custom date format because I can't access the system that is sending me the data and need it to make sense on for users on the front end.
`

Answer (score 1):

*1546926706* is UNIX/POSIX time where each *1* is a second after at 1-Jan-1970. You need a conversion to an excel datetime where each *1* is a day that starts 1-Jan-1900.

```
'Tue Jan 8, 2019 5:51:46 AM PST
=TEXT(1546926706/86400 + 25569, "ddd mmm d, yyyy h:mm:ss am/pm \P\S\T")
```

That's returns text, not a true datetime but it shows you the conversion and format mask.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it so clearly. I greatly appreciate your solution and explanation!